# How to turn off the narrator?

Tags: 8.1, lumia-520, narrator

Can you please tell me how to switch off the narrator on a Nokia Lumia 520?

I have tried switching off the cell phone but when I start it again, the narrator comes back. I also tried to put the phone on silence but it still doesn't switch off.

Answer (score 3):

There's two ways to disable the Narrator:

- Press and hold the Volume Up button for three seconds and simultaneously press the Start   button.
- go to settings -> ease of access -> disable Narrator